# Search/Filter a table in React: Replace null values with an empty string

Tags: reactjs, search, filter, null

I made a simple search function for filtering through a datatable filled with JSON objects from an API.

It works for most tables in my application but will crash it if any of the objects in the table have a null value.

my search function looks like this:

```
const search = (rows) => {
const columns = rows[0] && Object.keys(rows[0]);

return rows.filter((row) =>
  columns.some(
    (column) =>
      row[column]
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(q.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1
   )
  );
};
```

I just want to replace any null values in the objects with an empty string.

Can anyone help me with this in a simple way?

Comment: Could you please provide the sample of data on whch you are applying the search method ?

Comment: businessAddress: "address "
cityState: "city, state"
contractorEmail: null
contractorName: "Company."
faxNumber: "55555555"
phoneNumber: "5555555555"
ContractorID: 114
title: "title"
zip: "55555"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let newRows = rows.map((row) =>
  columns.map(
    (column) => columns || "" // return column if non empty else return ""
  ));
};

console.log("newRows", newRows) // rows with empty string
```